# How to limit number of characters being typed in ngx-tags-input in Angular 2+ application?

Tags: angular, ng-tags-input

I am newbie to the Angular 2+ and trying to build an application with it.

In our application , I would like to add ***n*** number of pincodes in `ngx-tags-input` and facing an issue in limiting length of characters to 6.

While referring to the documentation mentioned in [npm site](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-tags-input), I could understand that there is an option to set minimum number of characters in a tag but there is no key on how to set maximum number of characters.

I am googled a lot but unable to find the solution and requesting to help me find out the solution.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `maxTags` "maximum number tags allowed to select" in [doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-tags-input#api)

Comment: But I need to limit maximum number of characters in a tag

Comment: oh sorry, try putting a mask on

Answer (score 0):

in your .ts file put this code in formbuilder.group

```
 this.Form = this.fb.group({
  pincodes: ['', BaseImport.Validators.maxLength(10)],
});
```